# Why exported text ends with a highlighted percent symbol?

Tags: export, string-manipulation

I have recently updated Mathematica to 12.1. Whenever I export strings as text now, as in the following MWE:

```
    Export["test.txt", "a", "Text"]
```

a highlighted question mark appears at the very end of the underlying txt file:

[image: screenshot]

Then I need to put extra effort to remove. How I can avoid this problem?

Comment: I suspect that you are opening in an editor that uses this convention to warn you of a missing eol.

Comment: Look at `test.txt` in a hex editor and it should only contain a single byte `0x61`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include an eol, try this:

```
Export["test.txt", "a\n", "Text"]
```

Comment: That's it. It worked out! Thanks a lot!